# Как при наведении на блок позиционировать рядом с ним один абсолютный блок?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Допустим есть 4 блока на странице и 1 блок расположенный абсолютом. Как сделать так что при наведении на черный блок блок был  с правой стороны от черного блока.

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #000;
}
.left {
  float: left;
}
.l_b {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 250px;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
.r_b {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 250px;
}
.hover_bl {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 158px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="l_b"></div>
<div class="r_b"></div>
<div class="hover_bl"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно как то так

```
#bl1{
  float:left;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:#ccc;
}
#bl2{
  float:right;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:#ccc;
}
#test{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background:red;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
}
#bl1:hover ~ #test{
   left:60px;
}
#bl2:hover ~ #test{
   right:60px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/korolariya/pen/YWXNMN